# Best way of calling code from different projects in a C# solution

Tags: c#

I have a solution with multiple projects. Both the projects have Forms.

Example

MySolution

|____________________ Project1 (Windows Form)

|____________________ Project2 (Also a Windows Form)

Now I want to call the Form in Project2 from the Form in Project1. Sort of going like this

```
using (Form2 f2 = new Form2(myFile))
{
 //....
}
```

Moving Form2 into Project1 is not an option unfortunately.

What's the best way to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reference Project2 in Project1, See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx) - [Project References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a reference from Project1 to Project2. This can be done by right-clicking on the project in the solution explorer and selecting "Add Reference". Once the window appears (it will take a moment), click on the projects tab and select the other project. Cyclic references are not allowed so Project1 can reference Project2 or vice-versa, but they can't both reference each other.

Good luck!

Comment: May want to change that using. Though the way you reference Form2 doesn't require a using at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the compiled Project2 dll or exe from Project1.  Make sure Form2 is public, so Project 1 can see it.  After that, you can create an instance of Form2 in Project1.